# Why can't Next.js import files under a folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/layout's Codes\nextjs-blog\pages\posts'
> 1 | import Layout from 'components/layout'
  2 | import Link from 'next/link'
  3 | import Head from 'next/head'
```

Ok so this is the error message I'm getting what's going anyone have an idea

I have my components folder under nextjs-blog and the js file that gives the error is under posts

I didn't give much info because I'm new to Next js and don't know what anyone would need

it doesn't work if I do

```
import Layout from '../components/layout'
```

Desktop/Marti's Codes/nextjs-blog <- this is the path to basic nextjs folder
I've changed almost nothing to the folder in code and files

I have added components folder in the basic folder and in components I have two files :
layout.js
layout.module.js

then in pages I have posts folder and in there first-post.js
which is the file importing the layout files from components

Comment: What about `import Layout from '../../components/layout'`? That's seems like the right relative path from what you described.

Comment: I was pretty sure I tried '../../components/layout' but it seems to work thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
import Layout from '../../components/layout'
```

Thanks to juliomalves for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use relative path to import components i.e. `../components/layout`.

To use absolute imports like `components/layout`, we setup aliases like below in  `jsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

and use like this

```
import Layout from '@/components/layout'
```

Refer: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases

Comment: Ok the example I was using at the start showed me to use it like that but it did no difference

Comment: can you share the folder location of the component and your pages folder?